# Yii2.0 export function using kartik-v

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions

I am new in using kartik. Can I just check with you whether kartik is able to do below things? And how to do it?

1. Display date in different format than in db. i.e. in db it is displayed as `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MM:SS"` whereas on screen, I want to display it as `YYYY-MM-DD`.
2. Show subtotal and total?

Since in my report screen, im using a normal html to display data since from my understanding, the gridview does not have the subtotal function.

Below is my html:

```
$reports = $dataProvider->getModels();
$i=1;

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
echo "<tr><th>#</th><th>Item</th><th>Total Summary Usage Qty</th><th>Current Stock On Hand</th><th>Measurement</th></tr>";
foreach ($reports as $report) {
    $item_key = $report['report_item_key'];
    $item_model = Item::find()->where(['item_key' =>$item_key])->one();
    $item_e_desc_tx = $item_model->desc_e_tx;
    $item_c_desc_tx = $item_model->desc_c_tx;
    $item_qty_no = $item_model->qty_no;
    $item_measurement_tx = $item_model->measurement;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $i++ . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . Html::a($item_key, array('stockmovementreportdetailbyitem', 'item_key' => $item_key, 'search' => 'true', 'stockmovement_summary_from_sales_date' => $stockmovement_summary_from_sales_date, 'stockmovement_summary_to_sales_date'=>$stockmovement_summary_to_sales_date)) . "<br>" . $item_e_desc_tx . "<br>" . $item_c_desc_tx ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $report['total_summary_usage_qty'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $item_qty_no . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $item_measurement_tx . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination'=>$dataProvider->pagination,     
]);
```

Comment: I suggest to try to provide the best writing quality as you can - it enables you to attract better and better answers.

Comment: hmm. which part you do not understand? i will try my best to explain to you. :)

Comment: I think you should use kartik's `GridView `.